# Cross button became invisible after installing compiz

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, compiz

I'm using Linux Mint with Xfce 14.

I installed an old version of Compiz by mistake, but it was working fine. Then I decided to install the latest version, but after installing it the "Close" and "Minimize" buttons are not visible anymore.

How can I make them appear again?

Comment: Are window decorations visible and only thos buttons missing? Do you have `emerald` (compiz's window decorator, at least it used to be) installed?

Answer (score 0):

#### possible fix #1 - xfwm4

Try restarting your window manager:

```
$ xfwm4
```

#### possible fix #2 - fusion-icons

Try getting `fusion-icon` from the package manager. It should appear as "Compiz Fusion Icon" in the Mint Menu. Run it and it should appear on the panel. Right click and choose "Select Window Decorator", pick "Emerald" and then re-select GTK.

#### References

- [[ Solved ] Maximize, Minimize and Close buttons gone](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=110&t=71858)